# Confused about multiple java installation on mac

Tags: macos, mac, java

I have installed Java 7 for Mac OS X 10.9.
Checking Java version on System Preferences -> Java I can see Java 1.7.0_55 is installed.
Checking the version from Firefox using the [test applet](https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp) I have the same result.
However, if I run `java -version` in the Terminal, I get Java 1.6 (that is the OS X default version).
I am a bit confuse: where is Java 1.7 installed?

Answer (score 1):

On my system (10.9.2) the new JDKs are installed in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`

```
$ ls -l /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  102 10 Apr 00:51 jdk1.7.0_51.jdk
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  102 10 Apr 00:58 jdk1.8.0.jdk
```

However, the default `java` binary still comes from `/usr/bin`

```
oxygen:~ user$ which java
/usr/bin/java
oxygen:~ user$ ls -l `which java`
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  74 11 Nov 11:02 /usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java
```

Comment: This folder is empty on my system